# center align menu with equal spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu like this

```
Home  About  Privacy  Shopping  Contact Us
```

I want to show this menu in the center of its container (whatever the width of the container is). I can apply 20% width to these list-item but then some list-item has more spacing in between and others have little due to different sizes of texts

```
<div id="container">
   <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>About</a></li>
      <li><a>Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a>Shopping</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact us</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the menu fixed width? Are you asking how to horizontally center it? Are you asking how to evenly distribute the width of the menu items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Flex Box layout ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Cj4q/1/)):

```
#container ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal
    }

#container li {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    text-align: center
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that [this doesn't work in most versions of IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)...

Comment: I will add a gracefully degrading version (actually progressively enhancing) shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This method allows you to use your 20% width and center the items in your container, all while keeping the same width of each item.

```
ul { 
list-style-type: none; 
width: 700px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}

#container { 
width: 800px; 
background: #CC9;
}

li { display: block; 
float: left; 
width: 20%; 
margin-left: -5px;
background: #399; 
text-align: center; 
border: solid black 1px; 
color: white; 
}
```

which you can view here... http://jsfiddle.net/r6Wwf/15/

I added a negative margin-left to compensate for the border I added so you get a better visual of how it works. I also set the width of the `ul` to 700px. This could be any width.

To set the entire menu in the center of a container add this to your css:

```
ul { margin: 0 auto; }
```

And then add a width to your container. This is all in the fiddle. You can set the width of the container to whatever you want. I have it at 800px.

Comment: using 19% width leaves you with 25 pixels of excess white-space on the right hand side (even more as the size of the content increases). see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Wwf/11/). Better to use 20% width and a negative margin to compensate for the border or put the border on the anchor tag rather than the li.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay adding a containing element (`nav` is probably the most suitable), here's a good solution for you:

HTML:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav { overflow: hidden; }
nav ul {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; }
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px; }
nav ul li a {
    padding: 5px;
    display: block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/bKH79/

If you want each `li` element to be 20% of the width of the container, just set the container to have `width: 100%` and set each `li` element to have `width: 100%` (you would also need to remove the margin from the `li` and add `text-align: center`).
See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/bKH79/2/

Comment: +1 for interesting to find that nav ul {left: 50%;} nav ul li {right: 50%; }

Answer (score 0):

The best way to horizontally center elements in CSS is to give it a specific width, and then give it `margin: auto;`. Here is an example I made real quick. You can see the `ul` (blue border) has a width of 300px and it sits centered inside the 500px container (red border): http://jsfiddle.net/r6Wwf/4/. You can space the list elements however you would like.

Answer (score 0):

What is the container width exactly..?
ok Let me assume its `960px` now give `width` to your `ul` element so that the `list item` will not go in second line.Suppose it has taken `600px` now in this case your CSS for making menu items in `CENTER` will be:

```
.container{width:960px;}
.container ul{width:600px;margin:auto}
```

Hope it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple.

```
div#container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto 0;
}
div#container li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You would definitely need to write some JavaScript to make this happen. This is how I would do it... http://jsfiddle.net/rb39A/1/

By using a little bit of jQuery you can get the dynamically sized containers you're looking for.

Comment: You absolutely do not need javascript to achieve this! And when you resize your page the links fall under one another.

Comment: He wants the list items to be dynamically sized to the text inside... down vote was totally unnecessary. I'm just going to take the high road on this one.

Comment: which is totally capable with CSS.

Comment: If you even looked at my fiddle you would see the difference in what we're trying to achieve and why I'm using javascript.

Comment: @MichaelRader, question tag: javascript, css html. +1 btw.

Comment: Javascript is absolutely unnecessary here. This is very simple and typical css coding.

Comment: "some list-item has more spacing in between and others have little due to different sizes of texts" - this is what my JavaScript is taking care of... It looks at the widths of each block of text and adjusts the item to take up a proportionate amount of room.

Comment: on top of that... all your items are different width! So how does this solve anything!? What are you talking about?

Comment: Javascript should never be used to fix a layout bug. It shows that you're not as capable of wielding HTML and CSS properly, and it breaks the page for those with Javascript turned off (or without it at all). A page should perform its function without Javascript just as well with it.

Comment: @DissidentRage I totally agree with that. This is not a layout that I would use on a site of my own.. However this IS what the question is asking and it is up to the asker to decide if he wants to use an alternate layout due to the need for JavaScript here.

Comment: What need for Javascript? Unless he's setting out to make his layout defective by design, there is no need for it. Michael Rader's answer does exactly what is requested without Javascript. Just because JQuery coddles "strictly programmers" that don't know the design end all that well, that doesn't make Javascript the best answer. It is a bad design habit, it adds an additional dependence, and it leaves some portion of clients in the dark.